# jquery getJSON can not capture error event when respond status 500

Tags: jquery, getjson

When i access server by getJSON, there is a 500 status responding for me, but the fail event not excute. that's why? please help me. thanks.

```
var action = 'http://ship.mangocity.com/ship-calendar.shtml?callBack=?';  

$.getJSON(action, {startDate: "2016-06"})
.done(function(data){
    alert(456)
})
.fail(function(){
    alert(234)

})
.always(function() {
    alert(123)
});
```

The jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bugknightyyp/6jCHt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending data as a json object,
http://jsfiddle.net/6jCHt/1/

use `get();`

```
$.get(action, {startDate: "2016-06"})
.done(function(data){
    alert(456)
})
.fail(function(){
    alert(234)

})
.always(function() {
    alert(123)
});
```

Comment: The api is JSONP for cross domain. In the normal situation, the server responds json object. but when the server responds 500 status, i want to capture the error.

Comment: then why don't you use jsonp

Comment: If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead